# How to set the container height automatically maintaining the ratio

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I have an `img` object within a `div` object. I want to set the width of `img` (or `div`) and have its height set automatically to whatever is necessary to retain the original ratio of the image.

Suppose I set the width to `200px`, which is shorter than the image's natural width. When I do this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="foo" src="foo.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#foo{
  width: 200px;
}
```

or

```
#container{
  width: 200px;
}
```

the `img` has the height set to whatever is necessary to retain the original ratio, but the outer `div` has the height set to the inner image's natural height, and top and bottom margins are inserted between the inner `img` and the outer `div`.

I want the outer `div`'s height to be whatever is necessary to retain the original ratio of `img` so that the top and bottom margin between `div` and `img` would become zero. How can I do that?

Comment: Good question (+1). Is this code for an image with fixed width and a div, also with fixed width? Or will it apply to multiple divs, with different (sized) images and should it be dynamically?

Comment: @LinkinTED It should apply to images with different sizes. amol's answer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/n7ytp/1/)**

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="demo.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

body{
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red; //tmp added to check the height of container
}

.container img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function resizeHeight(){
 var resizedImage = document.getElementById('foo');
 resizedImage.style.height = (resizedImage.style.height * 200)/resizedImage.style.width;
 resizedImage.style.width = '200px';
 }
 </script>
```

And edit your image line to this:

```
 <img id="foo" src="foo.png" onload="resizeHeight()">
```

It should set the picture's width to 200 automatically, and resize the height proportionally.

Comment: I wanted to do it without JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry. That wasn't specified. Glad you found the answer you wanted. Mine will work, though. I tested it!

Comment: It wasn't specified in the text maybe, but JavaScript or jQuery wasn't tagged :)